# How to build a ISP (Internet Service provider)? What are the core components required?

Tags: cisco, switch, isp, architecture

I am trying to understand the cost of building an ISP. The core components required, licences, backbone and any leases. I have searched a lot on the internet and i am not able to figure out the basic architecture required. Consider the ISP will be serving only businesses and organisations.

In summary, I need to know what is the basic architecture to build an ISP

Comment: This question is really too broad to give you a meaningful answer.  you architecture depends on your size, number of locations, etc.   The network architecture, as you can see from the answers, is one of the smaller components of operating an ISP.

Comment: You really need to provide more information on what you intend to do. I've  build or participated in the building of 2 ISP in 2 differents countries with distinct technologies, distinct failover requirements. Price will really depend on what is expected.

Answer (score 3):

1. Find someone who will transit for you.
2. Get a building.
3. Buy a router and put it in the building.
4. If transit co is close, buy a cable and plug in.
5. If far, dig up the road or pay someone who has already done that to give you point-to-point connection to transit co.
6. Get some customers
7. Buy wire/pay someone to get point-to-point to them by wire or radio or whatever.
8. Build a support team.
9. Build a sales team.
10. Put them in an office or connect over internet.
11. Add up outgoing costs.
12. Divide by customers according to usage.
13. Apply taxes in all correct places.
14. Charge customers more than that.

There is of course more complexity in real life, but early dial-up was done pretty much exactly like that.  In some cases a single Cisco 2501 with a 64 kbit/sec leased line and a bank of modems screwed to the wall.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But what about the care technology to support. Like Router, switches, edge routers etc. Or does Cisco have any solutions for this ? I am trying to estimate the investment on such devices.

Comment: @john_avr You need to know your requirements in order to select hardware: number/speed of links; total capacity; redundancy for devices, links, power; backup; services you want to offer additional to switching/routing; ... Cost can easily vary over several orders of magnitude. You need to at least provide a basic business model.

Comment: ... everything depends on scale, speed, quality, and local economic, cultural, regulatory and geographic conditions.  Community rural wifi ISPs behave very differently to on-fire downtown video distribution ISPs which behave differently to generic domestic ones.

Answer (score 0):

For the required license this depend on the country regulations where you are setting . from technical perspective there is many things to consider but in simple answer you have two parts :

1. the connection between your ISP and the internet and here you have two options, either you have direct connection to the internet or through bigger ISP
2. the connection between the customers and the ISP and this will be the most difficult part , you need to decide how you will be connected to the end customer? through air or using some type of cabling ? in some country the last mile will be provided by the communication provider in other you need to reach your customer physically

Comment: What is a "direct connection to the internet" ?

Comment: The Internet consists of smaller and larger networks. There is no "direct connection to the Internet" - you're always peering.